# Cartoon mini-series from late 80s, early 90s

Tags: story-identification, tv

Okay, this is about a super obscure sci-fi animated series that I recall very, very vaguely.
One was a short animated series that ran during a week (I recall coming home from camp to watch it on Friday afternoons around 91-94). Possibly only a few episodes long. The character is some sort of outsider visiting richer worlds that I believe are floating or something. One episode has him embarrassing a princess by eating a plant.

Comment: Thanks, this is much better!  Do you recall what the outsider looked like or how he dressed?  How do you embarrass someone by eating a plant?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think it was because it showed him to be uncivilized or the like. I recall he dressed vaguely barbarian-ish.